# Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to make an app for gps detection . It is working fine.But after few interval of time array out of bound is occurring

here is code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private Button btnShowLocation;
    private String TAG = "app";
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private String mLastUpdateTime;
    private TextView tvText;
    private Marker mapMarker;
    private List<Location> loc;
    float distance, changeDistance;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private List<Marker> marker;
    double latitude ,longitude;
    private static final long INTERVAL = 3000; //3 sec
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private long mTimeStamp;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        marker = new ArrayList<>();
        loc = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }

        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        updateUI();


        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                updateUI();

            }
        });
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
        mGoogleMap.clear();
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        addMarker(mGoogleMap.getMyLocation());
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private void addMarker(Location loc) {
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
        LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
        options.position(currentLatLng);
        mapMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
        mapMarker.setDraggable(true);
        mapMarker.showInfoWindow();
        marker.add(mapMarker);

        Log.d("size marker", marker.size() + " ");
        long atTime = mCurrentLocation.getTime();
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(atTime));
        mapMarker.setTitle(mLastUpdateTime + " distance " + distance + "m");
       mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,
                15));
        Log.d(TAG, "Zoom done");

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected : " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();

    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged");

        mCurrentLocation = location;
        if (loc.size() > 0)
            if (mCurrentLocation.getTime() <= loc.get(loc.size() - 1).getTime()) return;



        if (!mCurrentLocation.hasAccuracy()) {
            return;
        }

        if (mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() > 50) {
            return;
        }

        loc.add(mCurrentLocation);
        addMarker(loc.get(0));

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(time - mTimeStamp < 3 * 1000){
            return;
        } else {
            mTimeStamp = time;
        }





        Log.d(TAG, loc.size() + " " + marker.size());
        //   Log.d(TAG, loc.get(loc.size() - 1).getLatitude() + "  " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        Log.d("distance", changeDistance + " ");
        for (int i = 0; i < loc.size(); i++) {

            if (mCurrentLocation != loc.get(i)) {
                if (loc.size() == 1 || loc.size() == 0) {
                    distance = getDistance(loc.get(0).getLatitude(), loc.get(0).getLongitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
                } else {
                    mGoogleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                            .add(new LatLng(loc.get(i).getLatitude(), loc.get(i).getLongitude()), new LatLng(loc.get(i + 1).getLatitude(), loc.get(i + 1).getLongitude()))
                            .width(5)
                            .color(Color.BLUE));
                    Log.d("distance1", distance + " i " + i);
                    distance = getDistance(loc.get(i).getLatitude(), loc.get(i).getLongitude(), loc.get(i + 1).getLatitude(), loc.get(i + 1).getLongitude());
                    if (marker.size() > 2)
                        remove(i);  // **Error is here** 
                }

            }
        }

        Log.d("distance new", distance + " i ");
        changeDistance = changeDistance + distance;
        Log.d("changeDistance ", changeDistance + "");
        addMarker(loc.get(loc.size() - 1));
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();

    }


    private void remove(int i) {
        mapMarker = marker.get(i);
        mapMarker.remove();
        marker.remove(mapMarker);
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            float distnceInKm = changeDistance / 1000;
            Log.d("distance km", distnceInKm + "");

            String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            latitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
            tvText.setText("At Time: " + mLastUpdateTime + "\n" +
                    "Latitude: " + lat + "\n" +
                    "Longitude: " + lng + "\n" +
                    "Accuracy: " + mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n" +
                    "Provider: " + mCurrentLocation.getProvider() + "\n" +
                    "Distance " + distnceInKm + " km");

        } else {
            tvText.setText("location is null ");
            Log.d(TAG, "location is null ");

        }
    }

      @Override
      public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
              startLocationUpdates();
              Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed ");
          }
      }

  /*  public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
*/
    public float getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        android.location.Location homeLocation = new android.location.Location("");
        homeLocation.setLatitude(lat1);
        homeLocation.setLongitude(lon1);

        android.location.Location targetLocation = new android.location.Location("");
        targetLocation.setLatitude(lat2);
        targetLocation.setLongitude(lon2);

        return targetLocation.distanceTo(homeLocation);
    }

}
```

Error is occurring in remove method but this issue coming during long distance tracking say 6 km .

Can anyone explain me why i am faces this issue?

Comment: Post your stack trace and indicate which line in your code the stack trace refers to.

Comment: You iterate through your `loc` list and use that indexer to access your `marker` list. If `loc` has more items in it than `marker` you're going to get an out of bounds exception. Have you tried debugging it properly?

Comment: yes , but marker list will always have less number of items then loc

Answer (score 1):

The error is so precise, you are going out of your array bounds, you are trying to get a position that doesn't exist in your List. Check how you are filling, accesing, removing and clearing your Lists.